# WPF touch screen issue . 4.6.2 Net version

Tags: wpf

I am facing some weired issue with WPF, Created registration page and on surface pro, first time it loads fine and Touch keyboard is always visible when textbox is focused and user can enter value using touch keyboard without any issue.

Once registration page is completed, and 2nd user tries to register again (2nd time) registration page is loaded. The touch keyboard does not open on textbox focus (unless textbox is focused twiced manully) and on moving to next textbox the touch screen is hidden again.

I have spend 2 days to resolve this, tried lot of things.
1) Process start tabtip.exe, but it is not loading keyboard.
2) Removed everythng from registration page just kept 2 textbox
3) using code behind trigger preview changed of user control and kept focus on first textbox.

Any suggestion will be apprecited .

Answer (score 0):

Is your project's .NET framework set to 4.6.2?

I do think they tried to fix this in 4.6.2, reading from here about soft keyboard support:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/index#WPF462

Another option could be to use osk.exe instead of tabtip.exe, this does seem to throw errors when debugging and in build if you don't change the CPU type in Visual Studio, eg:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I don't know what was the issue. But now I am creating new instance of tabtip.exe when my mvvm method for registration page is invoked. and is closed once the page is redirected to thank you page.